# How to listen only when child added !! not read all data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code

```
var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('offers/');

dataRef.once('value').then(function (snapShoot) {

snapShoot.forEach(function (datum) {

    keys = datum.key;

    var newdataRef = firebase.database().ref('offers/' + keys + '/users');

    newdataRef.on('child_added', function (dataSnap) {

        Notify("SOME TEXT");

    })

   })
})`
```

and I used `on('child_added')` to add a listener at user's point at this data object [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1qFU.png)
and unfortently this `on('child_added')` is working for the first execution with the entire data and act like it's `on('value')`

how could i make it truly listen only for child addition to this node

Answer (score 1):

I used a flag to solve this issue

```
var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('offers/'); 

var flag = false;

dataRef.once('value').then(function (snapShoot) {

snapShoot.forEach(function (datum) {

keys = datum.key;

var newdataRef = firebase.database().ref('offers/' + keys + '/users');

newdataRef.on('child_added', function (dataSnap) {

 if (flag) {

    Notify("SOME TEXT");
  }

})
flag = true ;

}) 
})
```

Comment: That's one way. The more common way is to include a timestamp in the items and specify the current timestamp as a `orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(...)` or to remember the most recent key your app has seen and pass that as `orderByKey().startAt(lastKeySeen)`.